# python urljoin directory not includ

Tags: python, regex, urlparse

I want to fix some situations about urlparse.urljoin.
Using this lib like

```
urljoin('http://xxxx.yyy/directory/','file.file')
```

gives me http://xxxx.yyy/directory/file.file but if i don't give slash at last in url like

```
urljoin('http://xxxx.yyy/directory','file.file')
```

gives me http://xxxx.yyy/file.file and this distrube me to write auto-collecting program.
can any one have solutions to fix this problem. I tried to put slash at last with regex and replace but these are not working properly when url is finished like

```
http://xxxx.yyy/zzzz/file.file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's behaving correctly.  If you're on `http://example.com/index.html` and click a link to `two.html`, you end up at `http://example.com/two.html`.  That's how relative URLs are defined to work.

`urljoin` has no way of knowing whether the last component is a directory or not.  You could try to guess, perhaps by looking for a `.`, and only add the slash if you think it should be there.

Comment: I know that urljoin is working properly. so i also tried to check with extension but some file linked without extension. Thanks to answer Eevee :)